# Does .NET Core SDK not provide compilers?

Tags: .net, .net-core

After following [the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu) for installing the .NET Framework and SDK on Ubuntu, I could only find two executables between both packages and neither are compilers. Where are the compilers and build tools?

Comment: Are you looking to the path for the compiler? Is dotnet build not enough?

Comment: Look at sdk/x.y.zzz/Roslyn/bincore, csc.dll and vbc.dll are the C# and VB.NET compilers.